# How to receive input signal on Raspberry Pi GPIO from transistor emitter

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi, npn, gpio

I'm trying to build a simple circuit that allows a Raspberry Pi to detect AC voltage in a piece of wire inductively.

I have the following circuit which basically uses an antenna wrapped around the wire to collect stray capacitance, triggering a series of transistors that steps the voltage up to 5 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f58r4h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit above works great, and the LED comes on when 120 V AC is live near the antenna.

My problem is that when I connect the circuit to an input pin on the Pi, the Pi reads inconsistently. When off, it reads correctly as off, but when on, it reads as if the pin is only receiving signal for a second every few seconds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn7ZTU.png)</sup>

I feel like it has something to do with the input pin not providing enough of a ground for the transistors to fully saturate, because when I put an LED inline with the input line it only comes on very dimly. However, I don't know how else to wire it so that it works.

Comment: You don’t want to put 5V into a gpio! 3.3V only. Feed your circuit with 3.3V. Add a 10k resistor from gpio to 0V

Comment: @Kartman It's unlikely that the output will be more than about 3.5 V to a very weak 4.0 V (given who knows what at the antenna), even with 5 V at the collectors. Clamped I/O protection diode currents will be quite low and probably safe against latch-up. That said, it's always better to just design it right in the first place. Agreed. But this isn't a great design to begin with. I'd go with a JFET input pre-amp stage.

Comment: Have you tried it with the LED still in place while connected to the GPIO?

Comment: I would think that the gpio alone would behave similarly to the darlington darlington configuration. You’d want some ESD protection though.

Comment: Yea the voltage at the output of the circuit reads about 2 volts, I'm almost wondering if its not enough for the pin to read.

Comment: @Kartman I'm not super knowledgeable on the subject, but even if i put a resistor between the GPIO4 and GND, wouldn't that cause a short? is 10K enough to prevent that?

Comment: @HandyHowie yes, the led came on but very dimly, leading me to believe that the GPIO4  was not allowing enough current flow to fully saturate the transistors.

Comment: You did put the LED in parallel with the GPIO, not series.

Comment: @HandyHowie Series because parallel would just short across the LED

Answer (score 1):

First of all the Pi only tolerates 3.3V, 5V is too much for it's input. You could clamp it with a zener, for example. Also what you are seeing is probably not a continuous signal but some impulsive one (at 100-120Hz line frequency maybe) so depending on when you sample it you have inconsistent readings.

As other commented it could also be that the signal is not quite of the level required for the GPIO to work reliably. A standard LVCMOS for example (not 100% sure if these are the level employed in the Rasp) should be below about 900mV to be read as zero and more than 2.3V to be read ad one. In between it's not really defined, it depends on many factors.

In general it's *not* a good idea to feed an analog signal to a digital port, unless it has a Schmitt trigger input buffer.

I'd suggest to clean your signal with a comparator and maybe some filter/monostable to make it more amenable to processing. Also that 3 BTJ gain chain is really ugly (sadly is quite popular on the internet), there are better way to make non-contact voltage detectors

Comment: Don't know how I clicked on -1, sorry! Will remove it if you edit it, it's locked now.

Comment: @awjlogan I sympathize, and will +1 in your honor. My fat fingers have gotten me into worse trouble.